# Уникальные комбинации чисел из двух массивов

Tags: php

Не могу решить задачу. есть два массива

```
<?php    
$arr_1 = [1,3,6,2,1,7,3,2];    
$arr_2 = [3,4,2,1,7,2,1,8];
```

Надо собрать из двух массивов 5 уникальных комбинаций чисел
например, [2,1], [1,2], [7,8], [6,2], [3,3]
Надеюсь на вашу помощь))

Comment: А в чем выражается логика построения уникальности?

Comment: Сергей Мишин, Просто так надо доя одного игрушка

Answer (score 2):

Для получения уникальных пар, достаточно, чтобы в каждом из входных массивов значения были уникальными:

```
$arr_1 = [1,3,6,2,1,7,3,2];    
$arr_2 = [3,4,2,1,7,2,1,8]; 

function uniq_pairs($a, $b) {
    // Для начала уникализируем входные массивы
    $a = array_unique($a);
    $b = array_unique($b);
    $pairs = [];
    foreach ($a as $aItem) {
        foreach($b as $bItem) {
            $pairs[] = [$aItem, $bItem];
        }
    }
    return $pairs;
}

echo json_encode(uniq_pairs($arr_1, $arr_2)); // 29 уникальных пар
```